# Suppress in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

i would like to elimate group based on expression. how can i do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JasperReports / iReport Designer: Can i show a band conditionally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524212/jasperreports-ireport-designer-can-i-show-a-band-conditionally)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the **PrintWhenExpression** value for the group band:

1. Click the group band in the **Report Inspector** pane.
2. Select **Print When Expression** in the **Column Header - Properties** pane.
3. Click the `...` button.
4. Type in an expression that returns `false` when the group should *not* be displayed.