# JasperReports / iReport Designer: Can i show a band conditionally?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have created a report as follow:

Multiple detail band
each detail band contains 1 table. Each table is linked to 1 dataset.

Can I hide the detail band whenever the result set of the query returns Empty set (no result found)?

how can I achieve this?

Comment: what kind of datasets do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "Properties" of each Detail band you have an option called "Print When Expression" there you can place logic that evaluates to `boolean`.

When you fill it with your logic and it returns `true` this detail band is printed.

So, you will need to have the information if the table will be filled in advance and cannot address the dataset within.

If your datasets are too different to do this, you should overwrite the Dataset for the main report with a custom one that gathers the information and sets the fields appropriately.